# Threading method doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, multithreading

I tried to send and receive at the same time using Thread, and only the thread is working, the rest of the code does not excuse.

My code:

```
def send():
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("Send Method")

thread = threading.Thread(send())
thread.start()

while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Loop")
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

only "Send Method" is printed

How can I make them both work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in this line

```
thread = threading.Thread(send())
```

What happens here is that your calling the send function, so it enters it the while True loop in send function, and it never comes out of that loop.
To solve this give the function as parameter without brackets
And you also have to specify the target parameter and give your function like this:

```
thread = threading.Thread(target= send)
```

Final code:

```
import threading, time

def send():
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("Send Method")

thread = threading.Thread(target= send)
thread.start()

while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Loop")
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```